How to make p5 js canvas tab accessible
I am trying to make a game using p5 js library and I want the user to be able to enter the canvas using the tab button.
I tried adding tabindex = "0" however that does not work. I am able to go through the navigation links using tab but canvas is not highlighted. If someone could point me in the right direction, would be great!

Please share a [mcve] of your code. Why do you want to make the canvas tab accessible, anyway? What problem does this solve for you?

Note that making something tab-able is not the same thing as making it accessible. Many browsers and screen readers intentionally only tab to interactive elements like links and buttons. Other keyboard shortcuts or commands are used to navigate to non-interactive content.
If you want to make game controls you're drawing to the canvas accessible, you'll need to use fallback DOM elements that mirror the game controls. See the accessibility guidance from MDN on the canvas element for more info.

https://shrutivese.pythonanywhere.com/
Here is my game that I am trying to make accessible. When I am inside the canvas , I am able to move between bubbles and burst them but if the canvas is not focused , then a keyboard only user will not be able to enter the canvas thus making the game inaccessible.

It's great that you are considering keyboard accessibility as part of your project.
Unfortunately, there's  no simple trick to getting a keyboard-accessible, screen reader-friendly <canvas> element. In fact it takes a fair amount of code and planning.
In general, avoid using <canvas> for anything that could be represented in a web page document structure. It is best left for 2D or 3D games, which have unique input mechanisms and tend to leave out users with disabilities anyway.
The <canvas> HTML element supports HTML descendants, which the browser turns into accessible (invisible) DOM nodes.
Basically you should recreate the canvas pixel data as an invisible DOM structure nested inside the <canvas> HTML element. The interactive elements inside this structure can receive keyboard focus.
Add click handlers to the invisible interactive elements (<a> and <button>, for instance), which map to the keyboard activation keys (Enter key, and Spacebar key in the case of button). Activating the invisible elements should perform the same actions as when the user clicks on  the respective visual area of the canvas with a mouse.
Also consider adding the same text, tables, and anything else represented as pixels in the canvas area as nested invisible DOM. This will aid screen reader users, who can navigate non-interactive structures.
But your question is more about visual feedback as a sighted user who is using the keyboard. This means manually adding focus ring outlines for each of the interactive invisible DOM elements.
This can be tricky, as you may need to update the canvas pixel data to draw the outlines accordingly.
Alternatively, this can be achieved using the DOM in modern browsers that support the CSS :has() selector.
In this scenario, you would create a matching <div> for each interactive element. Each would be placed inside a container <div> that immediately follows the <canvas> in the HTML, which gets positioned over top of the canvas.
You would absolutely position each of the matching <div> elements so they appear at the same coordinates as their respective visual area in the canvas.
Then, using some fairly complex CSS selectors, you can trigger the matching <div>s to show a focus ring outline when their nested invisible element is focused.
Here's the solution I tested:
<style>
  .canvas__container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .canvas__outlines {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .canvas__outline {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
  }
  .nav__link--about__outline {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .nav__link--products__outline {
    top: 20px;
    left: 220px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .nav__link--contact__outline {
    top: 20px;
    left: 440px;
    width: 190px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .canvas:has(.nav__link--about:focus-within)
    + .canvas__outlines
    .nav__link--about__outline,
  .canvas:has(.nav__link--products:focus-within)
    + .canvas__outlines
    .nav__link--products__outline,
  .canvas:has(.nav__link--contact:focus-within)
    + .canvas__outlines
    .nav__link--contact__outline {
    border-color: Highlight;
  }
</style>
<div class="canvas__container">
  <canvas class="canvas" height="500" width="500">
    <nav>
      <a href="/about" class="nav__link--about">About </a>
      <a href="/products" class="nav__link--products">Products</a>
      <a href="/contact" class="nav__link--contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </canvas>
  <div class="canvas__outlines">
    <div class="canvas__outline nav__link--about__outline"></div>
    <div class="canvas__outline nav__link--products__outline"></div>
    <div class="canvas__outline nav__link--contact__outline"></div>
  </div>
</div>

